# Magento 2 : How to fetch custom input data in product attribute form

Tags: magento2, admin, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

**I have created plugin for add textbox in product attribute form.**

[image]

> di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front">
        <plugin name="extension_attribute_edit_form" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab;

class Front
{
public function aroundGetFormHtml(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
)
{
    $form = $subject->getForm();
    $fieldset = $form->getElement('front_fieldset');
    $fieldset->addField(
        'stn_price',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'stn_price',
            'label' => __('Stone Price'),
            'title' => __('Stone Price'),
            'required' => false
        ]
    );
    return $proceed();
}
}
```

> Vendor\Module\etc\db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
<table name="catalog_eav_attribute" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Catalog EAV Attribute Table">
    <column xsi:type="int" name="stn_price" unsigned="true" nullable="false"
            identity="false" default="0" comment="Stone Weight"/>
</table>
</schema>
```

Comment: Is it possible to save data already?

Comment: No, now i have added manually but i will save with observer

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a data patch to create field in eav_attribute table. It will save data in db and fetch data in product attribute form

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class Data implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $categorySetup
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'stn_price',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Stone Price',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => 1,
                'visible_on_front' => 1,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            ]
        );
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

After creating this file

**Run commands:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade and others as required
```